# What will be the regnal number of the next Queen Mary in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, monarchy

The crown of the UK is a union of the crowns of England and Scotland. (And maybe Ireland too but that's not relevant to this question.)

This means that the current Queen is "Queen Elizabeth II" for all of the UK because she is the 2nd Queen Elizabeth for the united crown, even though Scotland never had a 1st.

Similarly, the next James will be "King James VIII". The two King James of England were numbered the 1st and 2nd, but they are the same individuals as the 6th and 7th King James of Scotland.

Both England and Scotland have had separate individuals named "Queen Mary I" of each country. When Queen Mary II became Queen of both England and Scotland, the two countries still had separate crowns. It was a coincidence that both countries each had one Mary as Queen so she was "The Second" in both countries.

It is now the future and a Mary has become the new Queen of the UK.

Is she "Queen Mary III", because she will succeed from Queen Mary II? or...

Is she "Queen Mary IV", because she will be the 4th Queen Mary in the combined crown of the UK?

Comment: Since the UK is actually _The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland_, Northern Ireland at least is relevant to any question about the UK monarch.

Comment: @sempaiscuba There hasn't been a King of Ireland that could cause a namespace collision as the two Queen Marys have.

Comment: I'm also leaving aside the strange situation of not including the Anglo-Saxon King Edwards in numbering.

Comment: There was never a separate numbering for the Kings of Ireland anyway, either for the 1541-1800 Kingdom, nor the Irish Free State. Despite its de jure independent status, Ireland in many ways 1541-1800 was very much treated as subservient to England/Great Britain.

Comment: And the English numbering was essentially reset at the Norman conquest. I wouldn't be too dumbfounded at regnal numbers often making no sense. The first King of Italy of that name being a Victor Emmanuel II (following the Savoy numbering), the first Emperor Frederick of Germany being the Third (following the Prussian numbering), and so on, mainly because it's part of the royal pregorative and in theory at least (usually heavily with governmental approval), a monarch can use whatever name and number they want.

Comment: Don't forget the [Pillar Box "War"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillar_Box_War), which was exactly about the question, whether the current Queen is "Elizabeth **II**" for/in Scotland, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If past practice is followed, she would be Queen Mary III.  However, ultimately, it will be up to the monarch, on the advice of the Accession Council to make that decision.

The current rule was described by the then Prime Minister, Winston Churchill, in a [Parliamentary answer](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1953/apr/15/royal-style-and-title#S5CV0514P0_19530415_HOC_222) on 15 April 1953:

> Since the Act of Union the principle to which my right hon. and gallant Friend refers has in fact been followed. Although I am sure neither The Queen nor her advisers could seek to bind their successors in such a matter, I think it would be reasonable and logical to continue to adopt in future ***whichever numeral in the English or Scottish line were higher***. Thus if, for instance, a King Robert or a King James came to the throne he might well be designated by the numeral appropriate to the Scottish succession, thereby emphasising that our Royal Family traces its descent through the English Royal line from William the Conqueror and beyond, and through the Scottish Royal line from Robert the Bruce and Malcolm Canmore and still further back.

(my emphasis)

---

[Mary II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_II_of_England) ascended to the thrones of England, Scotland, and Ireland in 1689, as joint sovereign with her husband, [William III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England).  That is the highest regnal number for a Queen Mary in either England or Scotland, and so the next Queen Mary should be Queen Mary III, if the practice set out is followed.

---

Note that Churchill (and the Queen) was careful not to seek to bind future monarchs in this matter.

---

However, you are mistaken on one point.  Specifically, when you say that:

> This means that the current Queen is "Queen Elizabeth II" for all of the UK because she is the 2nd Queen Elizabeth for the united crown, even though Scotland never had a 1st.

Queen Elizabeth II isn't the 2nd Queen Elizabeth for the United Crown  (Elizabeth I was queen of England only, and only [Queens Regnant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_regnant) are counted).

As is made clear in the Parliamentary exchange linked above, she is *Queen Elizabeth II* because there had been one Queen Elizabeth in the English line and none in the Scottish line, therefore the English line gave the higher number.

---

**EDIT** (requested by Spencer in the comments below)

When it comes to regnal numbering, **only kings and [queens regnant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_regnant) are counted**.  So, should we one day have a King Albert in the UK, he will be King Albert I, since Queen Victoria's husband, Albert, was [Prince Consort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_consort), and not King.

This is relevant to this question becuase, George V's wife, *Queen Mary* was [Queen Consort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_consort), and not Queen Regent.  She was therefore **not** *Queen Mary III*.  This contrasts with Mary II who, as mentioned above, ruled jointly with her husband, William III, and was thus Queen Regnant, and not Queen Consort.

Comment: Given the nature of the Scottish independence movement, this may become a moot point in a few years. This does bring up an interesting point that I haven't seen addressed. Should Scotland declare independence tomorrow, I assume that Queen Elizabeth II would still be Queen of Scotland as well as of England (with the crowns no longer being united). I have no idea how that would work in practice - I would guess there would have to be separate Coronations and separate Parliamentary "Queen's Speech"es (if that's the word I'm looking for). Would be interesting.

Comment: @Jurp Honestly, I can tell you what happened in the past, but I'm not qualified to comment on what may, or may not, happen in the future.  If there should be a future independent Scotland, the heads-of-state would presumably be initially set out in the Act of the UK Parliament that created the new states, and subsequently on the laws passed by those states.

Comment: @Jurp Elizabeth II is not only the queen of the UK, but also of e.g. Australia or Canada. But there was only one coronation.

Comment: You need to explain why George V's consort isn't Queen Mary III.

Comment: @Spencer Penultimate paragraph: "... _only Queens Regnant are counted_"

Comment: I think you need to specifically mention her as a Queen Mary who isn't counted.

Comment: Judging by the Australian and Canadian example, we shouldn't expect a different numbering in an independent Scotland. In fact, having been all Commonwealth realms monarchs also monarchs of the United Kingdom, extending the "highest number" scheme to them would yield the same regal number as the current one with England and Scotland.

Comment: @Pere Should Scotland become independent, the situation is likely to be different from the Commonwealth countries in that it will once again be "one monarch, two crowns" for the UK's successor states, as it was in the reigns of James I/VI and James II/VII.  However, as I said above the details would presumably have to be decided by the Act of the UK Parliament that created the new states.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - Predictions about future are hard, but I would see it as a transition from 16 crowns in the same head, to 17 crowns in the same head, so I wouldn't expect a change of rules.

Comment: @Pere My Scottish family see things differently.

Comment: To add to the list of numeral anomalies, her present majesty is Queen (quite separately) of, in addition to the UK, of Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Jamaica, the Bahamas, Papua New Guinea, St Christopher and Nevis, St Vincent and the Grenadines, Antigua and Barbuda, Grenada, Tuvalu, Solomon Islands, and Belize. In all of these states she has a notional separate crown (and throne). No separate regnal number for any of them.

Comment: In addition, she was formerly Queen of Pakistan, Ceylon, South Africa, Malawi, Kenya, Tanganyika, Uganda, Guyana, Trinidad and Tobago, Mauritius, Sierra Leone, Ghana, Nigeria, and Fiji, all of which have since become republics. In none of them does she (or did she) have the regnal number 'I', despite being the first Queen Elizabeth of all of them.

Comment: As regards the Scottish coronation, while it is true that there was 'one coronation' in 1953 (for her Majesty in respect of the UK, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, Pakistan and Ceylon)-and all these countries were included in the coronation oath and the floral emblems of them all were included in the Queen's coronation dress.

Comment: Should Scotland ever become independent, (which would probably result from the repealing of the 1707 Acts of Union) there would be a legal and customary precedent for the monarch to be separately crowned monarch of Scotland were the personal union to be maintained, as it was in the case of Kings Charles I and II, who were separately crowned in Scotland. Note that there was never a separate coronation ceremony for the monarch in Ireland, nor even a physical crown to crown the monarch with.

Comment: During the reign of King George VI, what name would have been used for the monarch now known as "Queen Elizabeth I" to distinguish her from Queen Elizabeth (wife of King George VI)?  Would people have started referring to "Queen Elizabeth I" when discussing the former monarch, despite the fact that there wasn't yet a Queen Elizabeth II, or what?

Comment: @supercat No, she was just "_Queen Elizabeth_".  Much as Victoria is just _Queen Victoria_ now, but if there is ever another Queen Victoria, then people would start calling the first one "_Queen Victoria I_"

Comment: @sempaiscuba: If during the reign of George VI, someone was asked "When was Queen Elizabeth born", would the response more likely have been "4 August 1900" or "7 September 1533"?  I can't find any reference to George VI's wife being referred to as anything other than "Queen Elizabeth" until after her daughter became "Queen Elizabeth II", making her "Queen Elizabeth The Queen Mother".

Comment: @supercat If they were asking about the king's wife during the reign of George VI, they would just have asked "*When was the Queen born?*"  After Elizabeth II became Queen, they would have asked "*When was the Queen Mother born?*"

Comment: @sempaiscuba: So I guess there wouldn't have been any ambiguity until after the reign of George VI, at which point the coronation of Queen Elizabeth II and the assumption of the new name Queen Elizabeth The Queen Mother would eliminate the ambiguity that would have otherwise arisen.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. (I guess it would just be making trouble to bring up Henrietta Maria, who (much to her dislike) was called "Queen Mary" in England).

Answer (score 3):

As sempalscuba said in his answer, there is no way to be certain what numeral a future monarch will choose to use, but going by the practices in the past it is most likely that a future queen regnant of the UK named Mary will known as Mary the Third.

I note that if Prince George (born 2013) has children, as he probably will, and if his oldest child is a girl and is named Mary, that will be the soonest that another Queen Mary could reign in the UK.  And considering the average length of generations in the Royal family and the present age of the Queen, the hypothetical oldest child of Prince George, whatever his or her first name will be, will probably not reign until about 2100.

However, I can point out that it would be equally logical for the next queen regnant of the UK to be known as Mary the First.

The Kingdom of Scotland dates aback to AD 843, more or less, and the Kingdom of England to 927.  In 1542 King Henry VIII of England turned his Lordship of Ireland (created in 1177) into the Kingdom of Ireland.  In 1707 the Kingdoms of England and Scotland merged into the new Kingdom of Great Britain.  In 1801 the Kingdoms of Ireland and Great Britain merged to form the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland.  In the 20th century most of Ireland broke away from the United Kingdom and the title of the Kingdom was eventually changed to the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland.

And it is perfectly logical to start the numbering of monarchs over again at one every time an old kingdom is abolished and a new one created.

The creation of the kingdom of Great Britain didn't affect the numbering since Queen Anne was the first and so far last Queen regnant named Anne, and the next three monarchs were the first British monarchs named George.

But when George III went to bed as King of Great Britain, Ireland, and France on December  31, 1800, and woke up as King of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland on January 1, 1801, he could logically have changed his number to George I.

Then George IV (1820-30) would have Been George II, William IV (1830-37) would have been William I, Victoria )(1837-1901) would have been Victoria, Edward VII (1901-1910) would have Been Edward I, George V (1910-1936) would have been George III, Edward VIII (1936) would have been Edward II, George VI (1936-1952) would have been George IV, and Elizabeth II (1952-) would be Elizabeth I, Prince Charles presumably Charles I instead of Charles III, Prince William William Ii instead of William V, and Prince George George V instead of George VI, and so on with as yet unborn generations.

With another twist, Queen Victoria of the UK (1837-1901), became Empress Victoria of India in 1876, and George VI gave up the title in 1948.

So if the UK monarchs were numbered as Emperors of India:

Queen Victoria (1837-1901) would be Empress Victoria of India (1876-1901)

King Edward VII or I  Would be Emperor Edward I of India (1901-10).

King George V or III would be Emperor George I of India (1910-36)

King Edward VIII or II would be Emperor Edward II of India (1936)

And King George VI or IV (1936-52) would be Emperor George II of India (1936-1948).

It is always possible that in the future Wales, or Scotland, or Northern Ireland, or England, might become independent, turning the United Kingdom into a divided kingdom.  And if that happens it might be considered logical to start the numbering of monarchs over again.

If Scotland becomes independent, the remaining country could be called the United Kingdom of England and Northern Ireland, and perhaps add Wales to the title.  If that happens, a future King Robert or James of the United Kingdom of England, Wales , and Northern Ireland would be Robert the First or James the Third, while a future king Robert or James of Scotland would be Robert the Fourth or James the Eighth.

And it is possible that Scotland might become an independent Kingdom before there is another queen regnant named Mary.  In that case the next Queen egnant of the kingdom that includes England (whatever name it might have) will be Mary III, and the next Queen regnant of Scotland will be Mary III.

And if Scotland continues to have the same monarch as the remnant of the UK (at the present time fifteeen other countries have the same monarch as the UK) Queen Mary III of the remnant of the UK and Queen Mary III of Scotland will be the same persons.

And if Scotland chooses to have a different monarch, there could be different Queens Mary the Third in the two countries at different times.

If Northern Ireland becomes independent, and maybe joins the Republic of Ireland or the USA, the United Kingdom might change its name back to Great Britain.  And then it might be considered logical to change the numbering of monarchs back to Great Britain numbers, ignoring the numbers used by monarchs of the United kingdom.  So under that system Prince Charles would be King Charles III, Prince William would be King William IV instead of William V, and Prince George would be King George IV instead of King George VII.

So even though precedents suggest that the next queen regnant named Mary in the British Isles will almost certainly choose to be known as Mary III, there is no legal need for her to be known as Mary III, and possible future events and/or her personality traits might make her Choose to be known as Mary I or Mary IV or some other number.

Comment: The current queen of Australia is Queen Elizabeth II of Australia. There was never a Queen Elizabeth I of Australia. "The Queen's Royal style and title in Australia is Elizabeth the Second, by the Grace of God Queen of Australia and Her other Realms and Territories, Head of the Commonwealth." https://www.royal.uk/australia It would be confusing to have her called different things in different countries. This precedent will most likely continue in the future simply for clarity's sake.

Comment: The suggestion that it necessarily takes eighty years for another Queen Mary seems unimaginative. It could happen tomorrow if only perhaps a few hundred people convert to Catholicism, or your own more morbid scenarios.

Comment: In essence, up until the 1953 decision by Churchill, with the exception of Scotland, the English numbering was followed.

Comment: A last regnal numeral anomaly: there were five Kings of Hanover:

Georg (George) III (1815-1820) Georg (George) IV (1820-1830) Wilhelm (William) IV (1830-1837) Ernst August I (1837-1851) Georg (George) V (1851-1866, died 1878)

Notice that the first three are identical to the British Kings George III, George IV, and William IV. Yet the numbering followed the British numbering even after the personal union of the crowns was broken in 1837 with the accession of Queen Victoria to the British throne.

Comment: And as regards India; there was never any reason to adopt a separate number: it was just an additional title adopted by the Queen, it did not reflect a separate independent polity the Queen ruled over, but reflected the British rule over India, and her suzerainty over the Indian Princes, continuing the practice of the Mughal Emperors. In that respect, it was as much a 'separate' title as 'Defender of the Faith' is.